# Desktop suddenly shut down and can't start

Tags: troubleshooting, desktop-computer

I was normally using my desktop, and then it suddenly shut down.
All other things in the room (e.g. routers, monitors) are fine.
I immediately cut off the power, and reconnected it after several minutes. (this might help or not)
When I tried to start my desktop, the fans and the cooling system will run for a short moment (less than a second), and then they're dead again. So I think the PSU is fine.
Then I unplugged, one by one, all hard drives, half of my memory, the other half of my memory, and the graphic card. The same thing happened. It seems that they are fine as well.
That leaves me with the CPU and the motherboard. There are two LED-like things on my motherboard, and they are still on now. I don't know if that means the motherboard is fine.
I couldn't find a way to test my CPU since I only have one desktop.

So what is the problem here? Did I miss anything?
PS: this is the first time this kind of thing happened

Comment: if your Desktop is Dell, this might help: http://www.dell.com/support/article/uk/en/ukbsdt1/SLN284978/EN?c=uk&l=en&s=bsd&cs=ukbsdt1

Comment: @nafas Thanks. But mine is a DIY desktop...

Comment: Your HSF might have gone bad, or become unseated

Comment: Is the Motherboard/CPU dusty? It might became too warm. Warm CPU's can shut down automaticly due to security reasons

Comment: I had this issue, it was the Power Supply. The momentary fan and light situation is not a PASS on troubleshooting. If you have a spare try it.There is a way to put a paperclip in one pin hole and then the other end in a ground, but I am not positive so I am not directing you to that. but the PSU would either start (that eliminates the PSU0 or it won't and the PSU is the problem piece.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different power supply. Momentary power is not a sign of a fully functional PSU.